# Changing average price in Material Master (MM02) programmatically

Tags: abap, bapi, sap-erp, function-module

I want to programmatically change the moving/average price(s) of materials for the following special case:

```
VPRSV = 'S'  (Standard price)
MLMAA = 'X'  (Material Ledger activated)
MLAST = '3'  (Material Price Determination = '3' (Single-/Multilevel))
period = current
```

It has to work when there is already a material document for the given material in the current period. All other special cases that I need are solved.

I am searching for the function module equivalent of changing the moving average price using `MM02`, not `MR21`.

Maybe `BAPI_MATVAL_PRICE_CHANGE` is what I'm searching for?

What confuses me is that I cannot find a parameter that determines that I want to change the moving average price and not the standard price. Did I miss a parameter? If not, does it change the standard price or moving average price?

And I'm not sure whether this function module is the equivalent of `MM02` or `MR21`.

Comment: Maybe this is an alternative for your requirement ¿can you check this [link](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ERPMan/Change+the+price+of+materials+as+in+MR21+using+function+modules)?

Comment: Hi Nelson, this code changes the standard price, I need to change the moving average price, although `VPRSV = 'S'`

Answer (score 1):

no, there is not such a function module. But you can use Bapi  BAPI_MATVAL_PRICE_CHANGE to post price differences to ML. With this you can adjust your price to the value that you want.

Comment: Thanks. Does `BAPI_MATVAL_PRICE_CHANGE` change the moving average when `VPRSV = 'S'`?

Comment: If price control is standard price than moving average has no relevance. BAPI_MATVAL_PRICE_CHANGE is the the equivelant to transaction MR22. But to be honest, I think you should contact an experienced Material Ledger consultant. I think you try to do things which are definitely not supported by the system (see also your question related to transaction CKMM). In the worst case you will create non-repairable inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `BAPI_MATERIAL_SAVEDATA` to do this. Several mandatory structures should be filled for the successful update of average price:

```
HEADDATA-MATERIAL        = P_MATNR. "material number

HEADDATA-ACCOUNT_VIEW    = 'X'. 

VALDATA-VAL_AREA         = P_BWKEY.  "valuation area

VALDATA-VAL_TYPE         = P_BWTAR.  "valuation type

VALDATA-MOVING_PR        = P_STPRS. "new value of moving price

VALDATAX-VAL_AREA        = P_BWKEY. "valuation area for tax accounting

VALDATAX-VAL_TYPE        = P_BWTAR. "valuation type for tax accounting

VALDATAX-MOVING_PR       = 'X'.    "update indicator

CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_MATERIAL_SAVEDATA'
 EXPORTING
  HEADDATA = HEADDATA
  VALUATIONDATA = VALDATA
  VALUATIONDATAX = VALDATAX

 IMPORTING
  RETURN = BAPI_RETURN
 TABLES
MATERIALDESCRIPTION = INT_MAKT
.
```